# Http endpoint that can launch programs on the remote server

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

So odd question.  I was trying to write a wcf service that when you hit certain services the remote server would run the specific program, with the idea that I could launch VLC or a web browser simply by hitting a url on my phone (the server is hooked up to my tv).  I got everything wired up and the code runs, but it seems WCF isn't able to launch UI applications on the remote server, I'm guessing that would be a huge security concern.  So I'm at a bit of a loss on how to continue.

Basically what I want to do is be able to easily send a command from my phone to get my server to launch different applications.  The server is just running windows 8, I was hoping a simple wcf end point that launched apps would be simple and easy to write, but since that doesn't work, what's the easiest way to achieve this?  I realize there are lots of software that can do this, but I'd like to write my own.

Comment: But it could run an at command which runs it in a few seconds time......... Or write it to a queue for an app on your server to pick up and run that is allowed to run apps

Comment: That's true, I suppose I could have another service running that does the lifting and the wcf service could send it messages?  I'll give it a shot